# Background image won't appear react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to render a  Component but it won't appear in my React Native app.

```
import {Text, Image, ImageBackground} from "react-native";
import React from "react";

export default function GetStarted() {
    return (
        <ImageBackground
            source={ "https://images.pexels.com/photos/235986/pexels-photo-235986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" }
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
            <Text>hello</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please use code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

first off, you need to close your `ImageBackground` component, & you need to wrap you 'hello' in a `<Text>` component (not sure if thats just a copy-paste error, but still)

second, the `source` prop requires an object, not a string ([see the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground))

see below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, Image, ImageBackground, } from "react-native";

export default function GetStarted() { 
  return ( 
    <ImageBackground source={{ uri: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/235986/pexels-photo-235986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"}} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <Text>hello</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```